# Throttling PHPmailer for use in Elgg

Tags: php, elgg

I'll be using the social networking software, Elgg, for an organization that needs to send mass emails to specific groups when they need to.  The number of emails can range from 10-1000 depending on the group.  Web host only allows 500 emails per hour, so I need to throttle the script to send one email every 8 seconds.

I'm using PHPmailer with Elgg.   PHPmailer says that I should use these two scripts (code below) in conjunction with each other in order to throttle the mailing.  I know how I'm going to use the code in the mailing script, I'm just unsure about a couple things.

1) I don't really understand the purpose for the safemode

2) After looking up set_time_limit, it looks like I should set this to an amount of time to allow all potential emails to be sent, whether it's 10 or 1000? Or is this a max of 30 seconds per loop in case it needs to timeout?

3) How should I set this to get what I need?

Links to PHPmailer describing code:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tip_ext

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tip_pause

```
 <?php

/* The following code snippet with set the maximum execution time
 * of your script to 300 seconds (5 minutes)
 * Note: set_time_limit() does not work with safe_mode enabled
 */

$safeMode = ( @ini_get("safe_mode") == 'On' || @ini_get("safe_mode") === 1 ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
if ( $safeMode === FALSE ) {
  set_time_limit(300); // Sets maximum execution time to 5 minutes (300 seconds)
  // ini_set("max_execution_time", "300"); // this does the same as "set_time_limit(300)"
}

echo "max_execution_time " . ini_get('max_execution_time') . "<br>";

/* if you are using a loop to execute your mailing list (example: from a database),
 * put the command in the loop
 */

while (1==1) {
  set_time_limit(30); // sets (or resets) maximum  execution time to 30 seconds)
  // .... put code to process in here
  if (1!=1) {
    break;
  }
}

?>
```

and

```
<?php

/* Note: set_time_limit() does not work with safe_mode enabled */

while (1==1) {
  set_time_limit(30); // sets (or resets) maximum  execution time to 30 seconds)
  // .... put code to process in here

  usleep(1000000); // sleep for 1 million micro seconds - will not work with Windows servers / PHP4
  // sleep(1); // sleep for 1 seconds (use with Windows servers / PHP4
  if (1!=1) {
    break;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: host limiting would suggest its a shared host, which is not ideal for a project like this.

Comment: I agree, I want it to be cleaner.  They don't need anything heavy from a traffic standpoint.  They do rely on being able to email their members a few times a week.  I'd have to figure out a way to sync member email addresses with a service like mailchimp, which is unfortunately outside my skill set.

Answer (score 1):

1. Safe mode is deprecated as of php 5.3 and removed in php 5.4, so if your install is relatively recent, it's a moot point: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode
2. Doing a set_time_limit() will reset the counter, so as long as your code reaches the set_time_limit() call in less time than the limit was set previously (e.g. gets there in 29 seconds, leaving 1 second on clock), the code will reset the timer and get another 30 seconds. However, since you don't want your code to be racy, you should simply disable the time limit entirely.
3. Personally, I wouldn't dump out one email every 8 seconds. I'd blast out the 500 we're allowed, then have a scheduled job to fire up the script once an hour and resume from where the blast left off. This will make things be a bit bursty for the mail server, but potentially more efficient in the long run, as it could batch together emails for the same recipient domains. e.g. all @aol.com mails in the group of 500 can go together, rather than forcing the server to connect to aol multiple times to deliver individual mails.

As well, if you're batching like this, a server failure will only be 'bad' during the few seconds when the script's actually running and building emails. The rest of the time the PHP script won't even be running, and it'll be up to the smtp server to do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be of quick and perticular help but i would consider an asynchronous approach.

This involves storing the task to send an email in a queue and having workers which process those tasks.

The simplest way is to just store emails in the database and have a cronjob running on the server which sends the emails in batches.

The better (but more complex) solution would be to use some sort of message queue system, like [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org) or the heavy-weight [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com).

The last and maybe most comfortable option from the top of my head is to use a web service like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) or [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com).